# Parse KML file with vba

Tags: vba, xpath, kml

I am trying to get 2 pieces of information from a KML file. I have some code (ref:K Buttters) in vba (as I want to add the data to a db). This code works perfectly and returns the coordinates, but I want to also get the data for the name tag. How do I amend the code to get this extra piece of information. information. Thanks

```
Public Sub readFile()

Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim ns As String

Dim nodelist As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim coordNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim XPath As String
Dim Namespace As String

Dim i As Integer    

'Create the DomDocument Object

'Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Load entire Document before moving on

objXML.async = False

'Don't Validate

objXML.validateOnParse = False

'Read in the file

objXML.Load ("C:\pcsect2.kml")


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Set up the appropriate (default) namespace

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Namespace = "xmlns:ns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'"

Call objXML.SetProperty("SelectionNamespaces", Namespace)


Call objXML.SetProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Define the XPath to get to coordinates

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

XPath = "//ns:coordinates"

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Select All "coordinates" nodes

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set nodelist = objXML.SelectNodes(XPath)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Nodelist contains all the Coordinates...

' note: Under view ... set immediate window to viewable to see the debug.print results...

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

For i = 0 To nodelist.Length - 1

    Set coordNode = nodelist.NextNode

    Debug.Print coordNode.Text

Next i

End Sub
```

---

kml file:

```
                <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
              <Document>
                <description><![CDATA[UK postcode polygons]]></description>
                <Style id="stylePostcode">
                  <LineStyle>
                    <width>3</width>
                  </LineStyle>
                  <PolyStyle>
                    <color>00ff0000</color>
                  </PolyStyle>
                </Style>
                <Style id="stylePostcode" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                  <LineStyle>
                    <width>3</width>
                  </LineStyle>
                  <PolyStyle>
                    <color>00ff0000</color>
                  </PolyStyle>
                </Style>    
                <Folder xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                  <name>AB10</name>
                  <description><![CDATA[Postcode sectors in the AB10 postcode district]]></description>
                  <Placemark>
                    <name>AB10 1</name>
                    <styleUrl>#stylePostcode</styleUrl>
                    <description><![CDATA[AB10 1 postcode sector]]></description>
                    <MultiGeometry>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -2.09646046762775,57.1512327554617 -2.0962834594401,57.1506128321186 -2.09610247782767            
                            </coordinates>
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -2.10596557515499,57.1385921418501 -2.10604057319705,57.1387481221535           
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                    </MultiGeometry>
                  </Placemark>    
                  <Placemark>
                    <name>AB10 6</name>
                    <styleUrl>#stylePostcode</styleUrl>
                    <description><![CDATA[AB10 6 postcode sector</a>]]></description>
                    <MultiGeometry>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -2.11311153246704,57.1365722876569 -2.11309853402536,57.1365692881912          
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -2.1113360807897,57.1427795678869 -2.11112010338182,57.1426645845693
                      </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                    </MultiGeometry>
                  </Placemark>
                  <Placemark>
                    <name>AB10 7</name>
                    <styleUrl>#stylePostcode</styleUrl>
                    <description><![CDATA[AB10 7 postcode sector>Details</a>]]></description>
                    <MultiGeometry>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -2.11383946866067,57.1372032022769 -2.11366248946505,57.1371542105275         
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                    </MultiGeometry>
                  </Placemark>
                </Folder>
                <Style id="stylePostcode" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                  <LineStyle>
                    <width>3</width>
                  </LineStyle>
                  <PolyStyle>
                    <color>00ff0000</color>
                  </PolyStyle>
                </Style>    
                <Folder xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
                <name>ZE3</name>
                  <description><![CDATA[Postcode sectors in the ZE3 postcode district]]></description>
                  <Placemark>
                    <name>ZE3 9</name>
                    <styleUrl>#stylePostcode</styleUrl>
                    <description><![CDATA[ZE3 9 postcode sector>Details</a>]]></description>
                    <MultiGeometry>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -1.33983120448744,59.8989006252828 -1.32301876923355,59.9016455421112             
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                      <Polygon>
                        <outerBoundaryIs>
                          <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>
            -1.32885903137389,59.8719950412819 -1.33463302343859,59.8690613106313  
                          </LinearRing>
                        </outerBoundaryIs>
                      </Polygon>
                    </MultiGeometry>
                  </Placemark>
                </Folder>
              </Document>
            </kml>
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted everything from the KML file? I think you just need to change the xpath. Try this after you have loaded the KML file: `Set nodeXML = objXML.getElementsByTagName("Name")
For i = 0 To nodeXML.Length - 1
    MsgBox nodeXML(i).Text
Next`

Comment: Your posted XML is not valid.  Most of the closing `</coordinates>` are missing

Comment: Thanks Niclas. I shortened the kml file. Thanks Tim.The coordinates were long and I deleted some of them for posting on here. I must have deleted the closing tags sorry. I managed to get it to work by adding a second xpath and node  
    XPath = "//ns:name"
                XPath1 = "//ns:coordinates"

                Set nodelist = objXML.SelectNodes(XPath)
                Set nodelist1 = objXML.SelectNodes(XPath1
Not pretty I know but it worked. However, I have another problem as there are more 'names' than coordinates and so when I write to file for each line, they are out of sync.